# How to pass a structure array to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, structure

i am a C new learner. and I was confused about this following code, which aims to print all the elements in a structure array. I know it can be done in main() directly, but when I put the printf(....) into a function and call this function, I failed to pass the structure array. 
Does anybody know why. I'm upset..thanks

my structure includes keyword and its count.  the initialization contains the constant set of names and the its count number 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define NKEYS (sizeof keytab/ sizeof (Key))

void traversal(Key tab[], int n); // define the function
struct key                        // create the structure
{   char *word;
    int count;  
};
typedef struct key Key;          //define struct key as Key
Key keytab[]={                   // initiate the struct array
    "auto",0,
    "break",0,
    "case",0,
    "char",0,
    "const",0,
    "continue",0,
    "default",0,
    "void",0,
    "while",0,
};
int main()
{
    traversal(keytab,NKEYS);
    return 0;
}

void traversal(Key tab[], int n){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n",keytab[i].word);
    }
}
```

Comment: The initialisations should not even work. You have an array of `struct`, so you ned nested braces. Also use prototype declarators for functions, the `#define` is dangerous at best (use the name of the type as argument; do not hard-code the names, this is recipe for disaster).

Comment: `struct key {... }` and `typedef struct key Key;` move to top(before .`void traversal(Key tab[], int n);`)

Comment: And, of course: " I failed to pass the structure array" is not a **specific** problem-description.

Comment: @Olaf nested braces are not required the initialisation works perfect in MSVC.

Comment: @WeatherVane: MSVC is not really a reference implementation of the C standard. This might be a legacy, but as I understand the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p16), this is not allowed (anymore). I know this works for nested arrays, though, but at least gcc warns about it and it is a very bad idea in general, because it is quite error-prone and beginners should definitvely not use it. Actually designated initialisers should be used for `structs` (although I think for larger hand-typed arrays, a positional intialiser list is acceptable - if properly embraced).

Comment: @Olaf I only discovered that by seeing a question asked here and trying the code. I do use nested braces; for one thing it makes the initialisation easier to read.

Comment: @WeatherVane: You are right. Just tested with gcc for `gnu11`. But once you enable `-Wall`, you get warnings. And there is no excuse not to enable these warnings or ignore them. So I assume the standard can really be interpreted to allow this legacy. Never used this (very questionable) "feature" and I discourage every beginner to even start using such constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare any struct, or function before using it, not after

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define NKEYS (sizeof keytab/ sizeof (Key))

// define struct first
struct key                        // create the structure
{   char *word;
    int count;  
};
typedef struct key Key; 

//then the functions that uses it
void traversal(Key *tab, int n); 


Key keytab[]={
    "auto",0,
    "break",0,
    "case",0,
    "char",0,
    "const",0,
    "continue",0,
    "default",0,
    "void",0,
    "while",0,
};

int main()
{
    traversal(keytab,NKEYS);
    return 0;
}

void traversal(Key* tab, int n){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n",tab[i].word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `traversal` function, you have an argument called `tab`, but you don't actually use that argument. Instead, you use `keytab` directly. So the function will always print `keytab`, even if you pass something else.

Also, you can avoid computing/passing the size of the array by using a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to mark the end of the array. The value `NULL` works as a good sentinel when your structure contains a pointer, e.g. `word`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct key                        // create the structure
{   char *word;
    int count;
};

typedef struct key Key;          //define struct key as Key

Key keytab[]={                   // initiate the struct array
    { "auto",0 },
    { "break",0 },
    { "case",0 },
    { "char",0 },
    { "const",0 },
    { "continue",0 },
    { "default",0 },
    { "void",0 },
    { "while",0 },
    { NULL,0 }             // sentinel value to mark the end of the array
};

void traversal(Key tab[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0; tab[i].word != NULL; i++){
        printf("%s\n",keytab[i].word);
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    traversal(keytab);
    return 0;
}
```